# Most efficient way to identify all the rows of a data frame column containing strings that are in a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to identify all the rows of a data frame column containing strings that are in a list. For only one string, it can be done via

```
df['Column Name'].str.contains('string_to_find')
```

However, **.str.contains** doesn't accept a list as an input which forces me to iterate through the list. The solution I found is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['Mexico', 'Province of Ontario', 'NY', 'Alaska', 'ONT', 'Quebec', 'QC', 'Quebec (Province)'],
                  columns=['Province'])

province_filter_list = ['ONT', 'QC', 'Quebec']

df['Indicator'] = False
for x in province_filter_list:
    df['Indicator'] = df['Indicator'] | df['Province'].str.contains(x, case=False)
```

What I would like to do is

```
df['Indicator'] = df['Province'].str.contains(province_filter_list, case=False)
```

The output should be the following:

```
index Province             Indicator
0     Mexico               False
1     Province of Ontario  True
2     NY                   False
3     Alaska               False
4     ONT                  True
5     Quebec               True
6     QC                   True
7     Quebec (Province)    True
```

My question is: Is there a better and easier way to do this than a for loop using **.str.contains** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["Province"].str.contains('|'.join(province_filter_list),case=False)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: Province, dtype: bool
```

You can try this...